# Can you please give me the name of عَنْ in this Hadith?

Tags: authenticity

حَدَّثَنَا عَمْرُو بْنُ عُثْمَانَ بْنِ سَعِيدٍ الْحِمْصِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا بَقِيَّةُ، عَنْ بَحِيرٍ، عَنْ خَالِدٍ

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note that what you have shared isn't a hadith, but a snippet of the narrator chain. We need to have all the information to be able to answer. And finally, your question is unclear what "name" is meant here? See [ask].